# Problem using estimator.train() after converting keras model to estimator model using tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am learning how to use tensorflow 2.0 and trying to use keras.estimator.model_to_estimator to convert keras model to estimator model.

I use the titanic dataset from https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv and https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/eval.csv as example.

In the keras model, I use DenseFeatures layer `keras.layers.DenseFeatures()` to automatically convert categorical features to one-hot encoding. Fortunately, I can train my model only using `model.fit()`.

However, when I try to use `estimator = keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(model)` and train the model with `estimator.train()`, the program reports an error `` ValueError: Unexpectedly found an instance of type `<class 'dict'>`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance. ``

I think it's because the function `make_dataset()` uses `dict()` which causes the error, but I don't know how to modify the code to fix the error.

The complete code is as follows

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
from tensorflow import keras

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

print(sys.version_info)
for module in mpl, np, pd, sklearn, tf, keras:
    print(module.__name__, module.__version__)

# https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv
# https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/eval.csv
train_file = './data/titanic/train.csv'
eval_file = './data/titanic/eval.csv'

train_df = pd.read_csv(train_file)
eval_df = pd.read_csv(eval_file)

train_y = train_df.pop('survived')
eval_y = eval_df.pop('survived')

categorical_columns = ['sex', 'n_siblings_spouses', 'parch', 'class', 'deck', 'embark_town', 'alone']
numeric_columns = ['age', 'fare']

feature_columns = []

for categorical_column in categorical_columns:
    vocab = train_df[categorical_column].unique()
    feature_columns.append(
        tf.feature_column.indicator_column(
            tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(categorical_column, vocab)
        )
    )

for numeric_column in numeric_columns:
    feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(numeric_column))


def make_dataset(data_df, label_df, epochs=10, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(data_df), label_df))
    if shuffle:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(10000)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(epochs).batch(batch_size)
    return dataset


train_dataset = make_dataset(train_df, train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=5)
for x, y in train_dataset.take(1):
    print(keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns, dtype=tf.float32)(x).numpy())

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns, dtype=tf.float32),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', dtype=tf.float64),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', dtype=tf.float64),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax', dtype=tf.float64)
])
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 32
train_dataset = make_dataset(train_df, train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=batch_size)
eval_dataset = make_dataset(eval_df, eval_y, epochs=1, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

# 1. model.fit()
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=eval_dataset,
    steps_per_epoch=627 // batch_size,
    validation_steps=264 // batch_size,
    epochs=100
)

# 2. model -> estimator -> train
estimator = keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(model)
estimator.train(input_fn=lambda: make_dataset(train_df, train_y, epochs=100))
```

The version of each library is as follows

```
matplotlib 3.2.0
numpy 1.16.3
pandas 1.0.1
sklearn 0.23.1
tensorflow 2.2.0
tensorflow.keras 2.3.0-tf
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem this week. It turns out that the convertor can't infer input names for sequential models. You can fix this by explicitly defining the input layers (more details on the issue on [github issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28976) and this [github pr](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/pull/188)).

You need to make two core changes to your snippet. First, you'll need to create input layers for all of your feature columns:

```
# build an input map for all features
input_features = {}
for f in categorical_columns:
    if f == 'n_siblings_spouses' or f == 'parch':
        input_features[f] = tf.keras.layers.Input(
            name=f, shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int64)
    else:
        input_features[f] = tf.keras.layers.Input(
            name=f, shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
for f in numeric_columns:
    input_features[f] = tf.keras.layers.Input(
        name=f, shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32)
```

Then, you can use the functional api to define your `tf.keras` model:

```
# use the functional api to build the model
dense_features = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)(input_features)
hid = keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', dtype=tf.float64)(dense_features)
hid = keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', dtype=tf.float64)(hid)
output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax', dtype=tf.float64)(hid)
model = keras.Model(inputs=input_features, outputs=output_layer)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Here is a gist with the full example: https://gist.github.com/justincosentino/f7f63642cb04f18ac7b896d3381db058.